# Grunt: Do i need to compile HTML on each save to see the results?

Tags: html, replace, include, gruntjs, partials

While developing an HTML project i'm using include-replace grunt plugin to avoid duplication of repeated contents (e.g. header, footer, sidebar etc.). My index.html file seems something like this.

```
<!-- @@include('header.html') -->

<p>Some Content Goes Here.</p>

<!-- @@include('footer.html') -->
```

Now, the issue is, if i visit this page it shows nothing (except `Some Content Goes Here.`), if i view the page source in browser the above code is there as it is.

Then i realized i've to compile this index.html to another location (you may say /dist/index.html). By doing so, now i was able to see the required results. But the issue with this approach is that whenever i make even a tiny modification in the source html, i've to compile the src files (having above mentioned code) to dist folder, and then i've to visit dist/index.html to be able to see the required result in browser.

Plz. tell me if it is the right approach in this regard or i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the way it would work. Some explanation

Some Content Goes Here.

When you type something like this in a file, you are creating a preprocessed template file, that would need to be passed through a grunt task to turn it into a form that is understandable by the browser (lets call it the compiled file).

It is pretty obvious, that if you make changes to one of the files included in the template file, you would need to re run the grunt task to generate the compiled file, which would then reflect the update content from these included files.

However, if you have a template file like this (i am not sure if grunt include-replace allows css,js to be inserted this way, this is just to give you an idea)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<!-- @@include('header.html') -->
<p>Some Content Goes Here.</p>
<!-- @@include('footer.html') -->
```

If in this case you were to make changes to style.css, you would not have to re-run the grunt task, because the compiled index.html would already have the same  tag for style.css

To ease the development process, you can use the [grunt watch plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch), which will watch all the template files that you have included in the index.html file, and if either of them changes, would re run all the necessary tasks automatically to generate the final compiled index.html file.